# How to create starting screen in SpriteKit with swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my game right now I've got a GameScene.swift and a GameOverScene.swift. When the game loads, GameScene.swift shows up and the game plays great. However, now that I'm done with the gameplay, how can I add a start screen that displays when the app opens?

Comment: I'm thinking the easiest thing to do would just be to create a new scene and make that the gameplay scene, and use the existing GameScene.swift as the startscreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the scene that runs when your app first opens, you will have to make some adjustments to the game's view controller. First change

```
let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
```

to

```
let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! sceneName
```

and this line in didMoveToView

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
```

to

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? sceneName {
```

This will change the opening scene from GameScene to sceneName, or whatever you called your scene. Also, you must declare you scene like this: `class sceneName:SKScene {...}`. You can create a new .swift file (cmd + n) to score this class in for easy file management or you can put it in the GameScene file. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind for my next project but yesterday I just decided to copy the code to a new file for gameplay and make GameScene the start screen.